# How to change "Preferred Network Mode" using adb without reboot?

Tags: adb, mobile-network, command-line

I'm trying to change my phone's (CM 12, Stock 4.2, both rooted) preferred network mode from "GSM/WCDMA" (0) to "WCDMA only" (2) and vice versa (there can be other modes too), using command-line only. Based on this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/111513/109933) I can make relevant changes into `Settings.db` using the commands:

```
adb shell 
su   
settings put global preferred_network_mode 2
```

However, I can't figure out from the logcat which or how many broadcasts do I have to send and with what extra key values. It is because of it I have to reboot my device to have the changes take effect.

**Ultimately, how do I change the network mode without the reboot using command-line only?**

**Edit**: Using aforesaid command in combination with [airplane mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/111513/109933) isn't working either.

Comment: `input touch/keyevent` is not an option since it would simulate GUI actually.

Comment: Related but unanswered: [How can I change preferred network type through a script (or terminal command)](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/86588/how-can-i-change-preferred-network-type-through-a-script-or-terminal-command).

Comment: Sorry, answered a liitle to early without noticing that you needed a commnad line solution only. Did you check - http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1468/do-you-know-other-android-keypad-commands-dialer-codes and tried with ##4636##?

Comment: @VishnuPrasadKallummel Thanks for the suggestion, and I'm perfectly aware of those codes, but I  need a command-line solution only. Check the text in Bounty's message.

Comment: To emulator see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67283479/4121942) adb emu network speed gsm

Answer (score 3):

There are some couple of ifs and buts. I have not tried this, but this is just an idea that comes to my mind which is an extension of my previous [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44347/simple-way-to-toggle-between-2g-and-3g-connection/82379#82379).

Through [this](http://xgouchet.fr/android/index.php?article42/launch-intents-using-adb) post, I learn that intents can be invoked through adb command prompt.

So, if the device is rooted and has Xposed framework, the above can be done.

Comment: +1 I actually came to know about this technique [here](http://qnalist.com/questions/5120018/2g-3g-toggle-without-cyanogenmod)  when the first time I was researching for my issue, but I think I couldn't recall it back when I offered this bounty. The problem is that I couldn't make it work with **Tasker** since the latter is executing it but the effects are not observed. However, command-line works and those who might need it, here is the command: `adb shell su -c 'am broadcast -a gravitybox.intent.action.CHANGE_NETWORK_TYPE --ez networkType 1'`. But thanks for posting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this post](http://www.josemauricio.net/?p=486)

KitKat:

```
echo "AT^SYSCONFIG=13,1,1,2\r" > /dev/smd0
```

Lollipop:

```
echo "AT+WS46=12\r" > /dev/umts_at0
```