# Ability to disable SIM card (at best periodically)

Tags: sim-card

I don't like the thought of being tracked via my cell phone. Thus I am looking for an easy way to disable my SIM card. I would like a way to automatically turn the SIM on every n minutes to check for calls, etc, and afterwards turn it off again. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: I am aware of the fact, that I would miss calls and mobile data would be disabled, too.
One can disable the PIN of the SIM, so it could be turned on automatically.

Comment: I imagine you could use Tasker to activate/disable airplane mode every *n* minutes.

Comment: Which Android version and device are you using? As GiantTree noted, using airplane mode  or [turning off the radio](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111587/how-to-change-preferred-network-mode-using-adb-without-reboot#comment141502_114433) periodically would achieve the goal but in any event, if the Android is above 4.2, then root access is required.

Answer (score 0):

If you kept turning it off, you would miss most of your calls, unless they luckily come in the few seconds you have it on, so it wouldn't be practical.

Besides, every time you enable the SIM card, you have to put on your PIN code, so you either disable it (bad idea!) or you keep typing it in every minute to get the SIM card working.

And it also would mean no mobile data, by the way, so no, I don't think such app exists. You can always keep switching airplane mode on and off, but that only solves part of the problem.